# Get the number of GPUs used in Tensorflow Distributed in a multi node approach

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, distributed

I am currently trying to compare Horovod and Tensorflow Distributed API.

When using using Horovod, I am able to access the total number of GPUs currently used as follows:

```py
import horovod.tensorflow as hvd
size = hvd.size()
```

A similar concept is available when using PyTorch Distributed API:

```py
size = int(os.environ["WORLD_SIZE"])
```

---

I would like to perform the same operation and obtain the number of GPUs currently in use for multi GPUs/nodes with TF Distributed official API.

I can't use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable as it would only work on a single node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few findings which answer my question:

- Equivalent of `hvd.size()`:  (the session must be started and initialized first unlike hvd ! Else you will just get "1")
  ==> `tf.distribute.get_strategy().num_replicas_in_sync`
- Equivalent of `hvd.rank()`: (the session must be started and initialized first unlike hvd ! Else you will just get "0")

```
    def get_rank():
        replica_id = tf.distribute.get_replica_context().replica_id_in_sync_group
        if isinstance(replica_id, tf.Tensor):
            return tf.get_static_value(replica_id) != 0)
        else:
            return 0
```

- Is TF Distributed running ? : `tf.distribute.has_strategy()  => True/False` (same remark as above, else you just get False)